# Version control system with working copy auto sync

Tags: git, dvcs

I have laptop and desktop computer and I want my working copy to be in sync between them all the time.
For now I'm using git.

For now my workflow is to commit every time to remote git repo into my branch and than pull that branch from another computer.
There are two problems with this workflow:

1. I have to commit partially finished code and write a commit message for it
2. I often forget to commit & push before I swtich to laptop so I just can't continue my work on it.

I wanted to automate it, but with git commit & push every 5 seconds doesn't seem to be a good idea.

**The questions**

- Is it possible to do an automated working copies sync with git? How?
- Do you know any other VCS can sync working copies automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that there is a VCS that is doing what you want. This is not what they are made for. Your usecase sounds more like a candidate for a network share or "cloud drive" (e.g. dropbox, google drive, one drive).